# set maximum memory usage of a python program running

Tags: python, performance, memory, ram

Is it possible to somehow limit the memory usage of a python program (maybe using pycharm) so the system would also be responsive while the code is running?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I get MemoryError